# How to mount iso file with selinux context

Tags: linux, centos-6, selinux

I am trying to mount iso file in /var/ftp/pub/centos

When I try to access those files using ftp in web browser it's not working . After troubleshooting I found that it's because of selinux.

`dr-xr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:iso9660_t:s0   centos
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:public_content_t:s0 CentOS-6.10-x86_64-bin-DVD1.iso`

Is it possible to mount iso including selinux ?

I referred [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/selinux-permit-apache-serve-contents-of-loopback-iso/) method (used selinux context for ftp) but it didn't  work for me.

OS I am using `CentOS release 6.10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also could not get this working. As the "semanage fcontext" + restorecon won't also work because of the FS being read-only, I would merely add an exception to allow httpd reading those files (I think this brings no significant security issue):

- set permissive mode to make sure all relevants denials appear in audit.log

  `$ sudo setenforce permissive`
- mount the ISO and read files through the WEB server.
- denial messages should be found by:

  `$ sudo grep denied /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep httpd | grep iso9660_t`
- build a selinux exception module with these denial events and apply it

  `$ sudo grep denied /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep httpd | grep iso9660_t | audit2allow -M my-iso-rules
   $ sudo semodule -i my-iso-rules.pp`
- restore enforcing mode:

  `$ sudo setenforce enforcing`

Comment: I knew that semange and restorecon will not work. So I used mount. Thanks for audit.log rule . Upvoted.